# Is it possible to change prefix after make?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, make

We all know that

```
$./configure --prefix=$SOME_DIR
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

can install `bin`, `lib` to $SOME_DIR. However, I wonder whether I can change the prefix of installation directory after running `configure` and `make`, without the need to run `make` again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `configure` script, the `Makefile` is generated, which can help you to compile your source code, which is usually done by invoking `make`, and provide you with a command to install it, which is usually done by invoking `make install`.

You can always manually change the makefiles by hand, and change the prefix. Sometimes it is easy, when you have a simple project. You can simply change the `prefix` variable in the single generated makefile and that should work. But this is not always the case. So, unless you know what's happening under the hood, I suggest you to reconfigure and recompile and avoid unnecessary headaches.